# Сжать или урезать базу данных MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql, база-данных, оптимизация, 1с

Имеется база данных в MS SQL 2012 размером в ~130 ГБ. Проблема в том, что в сжатом виде она занимает 9 ГБ, а если выгрузить данную базу в виде *.dt файла из 1С, то получаем до ~3 ГБ. Shrink средствами MS SQL убирает только 2 МБ данных. Каким образом можно диагностировать или найти и устранить проблему?

Comment: и какой объем из них логи, а какой данные? и что имеется в виду под сжатым видом

Comment: @teran, логи я только что очистил. 5МБ занимают на жестком диске. Я сейчас говорю о логах MS SQL. Есть подозрения, что 1С логирует большое количество действий, но в самой 1С я не разбираюсь. Есть ли такой механизм в программе, мне тоже не известен. Если есть, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что конкретно у вас занимает 120 гигов? Mdf? Ldf? Папка logs? Что-то ещё?

Comment: @PashaPash, я говорю именно о файле .mdf

Comment: @Алексей посмотрите размеры таблиц через Object Explorer Details в Management Studio (F7). Посмотрите настройки выделения данных (в свойствах базы там же, в Files - может там выставлен стартовый размер 100 гигов). Вобщем, ищите, что именно в базе занимает место.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio\Базы данных\Правый клик на базу
Параметры\Модель восстановления\
выставить в <Простая>
Если есть свободное время, после указанных выше действий - сделать реструктуризацию, выгрузить в dt. Затем загрузить из dt

Comment: Эта модель изменяет степень логирования. При создании базы данных, я всегда выбираю "простую" модель. Сейчас логи очищены и занимают ~5МБ

Comment: см также: Конфигуратор\Администрирование\Настройка журнала регистрации; Хотя этот журнал ведется в отдельном файле и не попадает в SQL-бекап базы